# Universal app acting up on iPad iOS5

Tags: ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad, ios-universal-app

I've been working on a universal app. So far everything is good. During final testing it turns out that the app is not working with older OS (5.0 and 5.1). It initially showed a white blank screen. After my some workout it started to show the views but in the wrong Orientations. My app only supports Landscape orientations on iPad. With the latest OS everything works perfect. On iPhone, even with older OS, there is no problem at all. 
About architecture, I am using a tab bar controller. each tab contains a UISplitViewController . Kindly help me out. If there's anything else needed let me know. I'll post that too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check this:

https://github.com/alexth/TBSV

It is a sample of how to use UISplitViewController inside UITabBar, but if you use more than one split you may stuck with an issue. Every split is signed to the same delegate so you will have guaranteed problem with tracking of changing orientation in different splits